# Getting empty file while converting XML to CSV file Pandas Python

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing, elementtree

This is my XML file

```
<Lieferantenbestellungen>
  <Lieferantenbestellung>
    <Jahr>2021</Jahr>
    <Nummer>1</Nummer>
    <Datum>2021-01-07</Datum>
    <Lieferant_ID>459</Lieferant_ID>
    <Positionen>
      <Position Artikel="MCGPXO96" Bezeichnung="Refined Rubber Tuna" Menge="1" />
      <Position Artikel="IYTAFI28" Bezeichnung="Generic Cotton Chicken" Menge="8" />
    </Positionen>
  </Lieferantenbestellung>
</Lieferantenbestellungen>
```

I want to extract the Lieferant_ID, Artikel, Bezeichnung, Bezeichnung and Menge from the file.

I have this python code:

```
with open('Lieferantenbestellungen.xml', 'r') as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), 'lxml')

# Get the data you want
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(
  [el.text for el in soup.find_all('Lieferant_ID')],
  [el.text for el in soup.find_all('Artikel')],
  [el.text for el in soup.find_all('Bezeichnung')],
  [el.text for el in soup.find_all('Menge')]
)), columns=['Lieferant_ID', 'Artikel', 'Bezeichnung', 'Menge'])

# Dump to csv
df.to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
```

When I run the code it generates the CSV file but it's empty. Does anyone have any idea of what am I doing wrong?

Expected CSV output:
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `soup.find_all('Lieferant_ID')`, what do you get?

Comment: Returns Empty list

Comment: Right, because `BeautifulSoup(markup, "lxml")` reads it as html, you need to do `(markup, "xml")`. What is the dataframe you expect to get from this xml?

Comment: I have added in the description "Expected output"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pandas now has [`.read_xml()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html) which you can use directly.

```
>>> pd.read_xml('Lieferantenbestellungen.xml', xpath='.//Lieferant_ID | .//Position')
   Lieferant_ID   Artikel             Bezeichnung  Menge
0         459.0      None                    None    NaN
1           NaN  MCGPXO96     Refined Rubber Tuna    1.0
2           NaN  IYTAFI28  Generic Cotton Chicken    8.0
```

You can `.ffill()` and `.dropna()` to "align" the results.

```
>>> df = pd.read_xml('Lieferantenbestellungen.xml', xpath='.//Lieferant_ID | .//Position')
>>> df['Lieferant_ID'] = df['Lieferant_ID'].ffill()
>>> df.dropna()
   Lieferant_ID   Artikel             Bezeichnung  Menge
1         459.0  MCGPXO96     Refined Rubber Tuna    1.0
2         459.0  IYTAFI28  Generic Cotton Chicken    8.0
```

Comment: This doesn't work if there are multiple `Lieferantenbestellung` records because the Artikel and other columns from the last `Lieferant_ID = 459` record are ffilled into the next `Lieferant_ID` record, which prevents it from being dropped by the `dropna()`

Comment: For example, if `read_xml()` gives [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idwEp.png), we'd expect rows 0 and 3 to be dropped but `ffil()` does [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDTAJ.png), and row 3 won't be dropped

Comment: Ah yes - just the single column should be `ffill()`ed - thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

To parse xml, you need to do `soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, "xml")`, not `"lxml"`.

When you do this, `soup.find_all('Lieferant_ID')` returns `['459']`.

However, doing `find_all()` a bunch of times isn't a great idea because you have multiple `Positionen` tags per `Lieferantenbestellung`. Instead, I suggest you `find_all("Lieferantenbestellung")`, and then process each of these tags.

Also, for debugging, it's easier if you split your code over multiple lines instead of stuffing everything into a single line.

```
with open('Lieferantenbestellungen.xml', 'r') as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), 'lxml')

rows = []
for tag in soup.find_all("Lieferantenbestellung")
    lief_id = tag.findChild("Lieferant_ID")
    if lief_id is None:
        continue
    for ptag in tag.findChild("Positionen").findChildren("Position"):
        row = dict() # Make a new row
        row["Lieferant_ID"] = lief_id.text
        row["Artikel"] = ptag.attrs["Artikel"]
        row["Bezeichnung"] = ptag.attrs["Bezeichnung"]
        row["Menge"] = ptag.attrs["Menge"]
        rows.append(row)
```

Now, you can create your dataframe using `pd.DataFrame.from_records()`

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows)

  Lieferant_ID   Artikel             Bezeichnung Menge
0          459  MCGPXO96     Refined Rubber Tuna     1
1          459  IYTAFI28  Generic Cotton Chicken     8
```